# How to Save Emgu.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte> to byte array?

Tags: c#, emgucv

What is a simple way to save a grayscale Emgu Image to a byte array in C#?

```
var outputImage = new Emgu.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte>(columns, rows);
byte[] outputArray = outputImage.???
```

Comment: @rory.ap yes.  All the links are byte array to Image, not the other way around.

Comment: @rory.ap that's System.Drawing.Image not Emgu Image.  I'll edit the title to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
var outputImage = new Emgu.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, Byte>(columns, rows);
var converter = new ImageConverter();
var outputArray = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(outputImage.ToBitmap(), typeof(byte[]));
```